# How do I use a symbolically link device support from Xcode 10 to Xcode 9 for iOS 12 beta devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Does anyone have the paths that I need to symbolically link device support from Xcode 10 to Xcode 9 so that I can debug apps built with Xcode 9 on iOS 12 beta devices?

Comment: Looks like your question was duplicated a fortnight later by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215836/ios-12-not-supported-by-xcode-9-4-could-not-locate-device-support-files, which has some possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the terminal command for the latest Xcode 10 Beta 4:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/12.0\ \(16A5327d\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

Also here is an mostly up to date list for other versions:
https://gist.github.com/ethanhuang13/b9b4b875db9b49a124e2af194b97be68