# iOS 12 not supported by Xcode 9.4 : Could not locate device support files

Tags: ios, xcode, beta, xcode10, ios12

> This iPhone 8 (Model A1863, A1905, A1906, A1907) is running iOS 12.0 (16A5308e), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode. (Version 9.4.1 (9F2000))

- can anyone help with iOS **12.x device support files** from Xcode 10 beta?

Comment: See this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815085/could-not-locate-device-support-files-ios/53815843?noredirect=1#comment99566203_53815843

Answer (score 73, accepted):

iOS 12 is only supported by the beta of Xcode 10 or higher.

If you want to use your iPhone 8 with this iOS version (NOT RECOMMENDED) with your Xcode 9.4 you can try to download the last beta of Xcode 10 and after connecting the iPhone to the mac go to this folder:

> /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

You can see the iOS version folder of the iPhone, copy and past it to the same location in your Xcode 9.4 folder.

After this you should be able to deploy to your iPhone 8.

Comment: I'm struggling with adding iOS 12 DeviceSupport to Xcode 9.3. The xcode itself is not recognizing it even after restart. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you check again the iOS version of the folder copied and the path where you copy? Are you sure you made the copy after the iPhone was recognized?

Comment: Yes. The copy was made after the iPhone was recognized. Should I see in Build Settings -> Base SDK -> Latest iOS (iOS 12.0) ? It still shows 11.3

Comment: UPDATE: It worked! Fixing my signing certificates made it run on the iPad although the Xcode did not show 12.0 in Base SDK

Comment: Great, it works for me! I have Xcode 9.4 and iPhone 5S with iOS 12.0 updated. 

Here are steps I did: 1) Download Xcode_10.1_Beta_2.xip file from Apple; 2) extract the package; 3) Don't run Xcode 10 beta. I had trouble to link to all dependent frameworks, and it massed up Xcode 9.4 projects as well; 4) follow the above link to copy supported 12 folders from Xcode 10. beta to Xcode 9.4. Restart Xcode and I can run my product from Xcode 9.4 on my iPhone 5s device.

Answer (score 49):

As answered by @Kerberos you can copy the [**iOS 12 device support files**](https://github.com/Yatko/iOS-device-support-files) to:

> /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

https://github.com/Yatko/iOS-device-support-files

Comment: I could not find Xcode10.app under /Applications. What am I missing?

Comment: @CoolDocMan find your XCode app and use the path where it is.

Comment: When I click on Xcode it just launches Xcode rather than taking me to subdirectories.  How can I get to this directory?.  I am running Xcode 8.3 for complex reasons, not Xcode 10

Comment: @user6631314 you can right click and click show package contents on your mac.

Comment: @CoolDocMan in the Applications folder, right Click on XCode>Show Package Content.

Comment: after clicking 'show package content' there is no 'Developer' folder

Answer (score 11):

The link provided by Yatko is not supporting the newest iOS 12 versions (public release).

This repository has more iOS versions to offer: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Copy the files to the same path as described by Kerberos.

Answer (score 11):

Another convenient way to achieve this without downloading Xcode 10.

https://github.com/sauravexodus/xcode-9-ios-12-support

Note: If you have multiple Xcode versions then be careful with the path written in `install.sh` file.

Comment: Updated to support iOS 12.1 as well :)

Comment: Do I need to change 'Xcode.app' to '[my-app-name].app' in install.sh?

Comment: Yes, @user1932595 you should mention the complete path properly.

Comment: Updated to support upto iOS 12.2.3

Answer (score 2):

[Just download latest OS SDK (iOS 12.2)](https://github.com/IMHitesh/iOS-DeviceSupport) and paste it on [respective location](https://github.com/IMHitesh/iOS-DeviceSupport/wiki).

## Downloadable URL:

[13.2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ggY8T6CTku4W9plggocWGswUDtXwqiEW)

[13.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aTUgE6_kmyd6NXe9KZKQvrxeLjvS0ncU)

[13.0](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16tPgsaX3-byBOoPrpZVe6q5O2SoBATU0)

[12.4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19Q8Y4OevMyma2wSnwVMw9mQrRzBTlFEv)

[12.3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U-xfto-cr740jaN8NeEJR4SfPG1zH5Lf)

[12.2 (16E226)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OTbUpMl44upB7jGYJaMDWuiOMJg_1oiZ)

[12.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y22bXcRzFIRrzGY8-qcsEz4tumzkYr2r)

[12.0 (16A5288q)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aauEs7Dij1RrwIgWIhVz-zx5x94MNzQl)

[11.4 (15F5037c)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14hC_7x02j_mg7FrOua57tjGx7mICfEtS)

[11.3 (15E5189d)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XJISl5O2S59VMAXqbEYf9MNvK_V6jp2e)

[11.2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D1ucSibO3ZC-jWmE8ncLm0Qc-JORpUJq)

[11.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bpNneKEH1nScha1Ga4MNmz9E756KLMpo)

[11.0 (15A372)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bg7Sy6dfHxiyFHtEfANVOcvcsFKs4SjY)

[10.3 (14E5239d)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AAsSn9-lCOT-kJ4gdvum7j6esjMLV-by)

[10.2 (14C89)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rX_63Uq9H6EzWEQqoEwkES3Wm7xtRkm9)

[10.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D3lucV47qORcHQHMK3X-ObA4rjVrGZoP)

[10.0 (14A5339a)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z-nj8eNUBv4qOX88dXZQS6dId0JOPAki)

**Follow below step.**

1) Unzipped downloaded file

2) Right click on Xcode and click on `Show Package Content`

3) Then paste your file on path

```
Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport
```

4) Restart Xcode

[image]

Is it very convenient, saving the trouble of updating Xcode. what? You can't find a new Device Support file! Ok, you can copy it out from your friend's latest Xcode, or [download from here](https://github.com/IMHitesh/iOS-DeviceSupport/wiki)

## Update:

The added iOS Disk image for iOS 13.0, 12.3 and iOS 12.4

Comment: *NOTE:-* 12.4 contains support file for 12.2 (16E226)