# Could not locate device support files: iOS

Tags: ios, xcode10

I am using Xcode 10.0 and running in 12.1.1(16C50). It was given below error.

> iOS 12.1.1 not supported by Xcode 10.0: Could not locate device
>   support files

[image]

Comment: You need to update to Xcode 10.1, that is the version which supports iOS 12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade your `Xcode` IDE to `10.1`.

Xcode 10.1 Release Notes can be found at, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes/

[image: xcode]

Answer (score 18):

[Just download latest OS SDK(Available iOS 9 to iOS 14)](https://github.com/IMHitesh/iOS-DeviceSupport) and paste it on [respective location](https://github.com/IMHitesh/iOS-DeviceSupport/wiki).

## Follow the below step.

1. Unzipped downloaded file
2. Right-click on Xcode and click on `Show Package Content`
3. then paste your file on path

> Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platforms > DeviceSupport

4. Restart Xcode

[image]

Is it very convenient, saving the trouble of updating Xcode. what? You can't find a new Device Support file! Ok, you can copy it out from your friend's latest Xcode, or [download from here](https://github.com/IMHitesh/iOS-DeviceSupport/wiki)

## Update:

> The added iOS Disk image for iOS 12.4, 12.3, 13.0, and iOS 14.0

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri Thanks for your reminder!. Added in GitHub and Answer too

Comment: @Sumeet.Jain I have added for 12.4 and Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Download Developer disk image for iOS 12.1 from https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases
and perform following steps

1. Unzipped downloaded file
2. Right click on Xcode and click on "Show Package Content"
3. Then paste your file on path "Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport"
4. Restart Xcode

Thats It....

Comment: sorry i downVoted and its working now :( after restarting Xcode multiple times. Though it not shows Version in target but it runs on device.