# SDK issues for release in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, release

SDK Version Issue.

```
This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, 
included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later,
included in Xcode 10.1 or later.
```

I got this issue on release the app to app store.How can I try to solve this?
[image]

> My development target is 11.4 in Xcode 9

When I tried to change developemt target to 12.1 then I got another more issue
[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of Xcode. All of your apps need to comply with these terms if you have Xcode 10.1. Because according to apple , Now all apps submitted to the AppStore must have the 12.1 SDK or they will be rejected.

Comment: Can I use SDK 12.1 in xcode 9?So I developed my app with Swift 3

Comment: See this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215836/ios-12-not-supported-by-xcode-9-4-could-not-locate-device-support-files